# Shell script ran on multiuser environment

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a linux server and there contains an important script xyz.sh. At times there will be 10-50 users logged into that machine. Is it possible to find who is running the script? Also, is it possible to get a log who all have ran the script xyz.sh; means is it possible to extract a history of script run?

Comment: Instead of using system management tools, you could modify the script to create a usage log.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple on-the-fly check about the owners' script while it's runnging you can use:

```
$ ps -e -o euid,pid,euser,state,command | grep "xyz.sh"|grep -v grep
0 31096 root     S /bin/bash ./xyz.sh
1000 31030 ale      S /bin/bash ./xyz.sh
```

It should be possible to log the ps output with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SECONDS=5
TARGET=xyz.sh
OUT=/var/tmp/xyz_history.log

while true
do
sleep $SECONDS
echo "$(date '+TIME:%H:%M:%S';ps -e -opid,user,command|grep $TARGET | grep -v grep)"
done >> $OUT

exit 0
```

The output:

```
$ tail -f /var/tmp/xyz_history.log
TIME:14:13:37
  496 postgres /bin/bash ./xyz.sh
  625 ale      /bin/bash ./xyz.sh
32137 root     /bin/bash ./xyz.sh
TIME:14:13:38
  496 postgres /bin/bash ./xyz.sh
  625 ale      /bin/bash ./xyz.sh
32137 root     /bin/bash ./xyz.sh
TIME:14:13:39
  496 postgres /bin/bash ./xyz.sh
  625 ale      /bin/bash ./xyz.sh
TIME:14:13:40
  496 postgres /bin/bash ./xyz.sh
  625 ale      /bin/bash ./xyz.sh
...
```

This is not a clean solution of course. If you can install packages on the system and run commands as superuser, a better solution is using `lastcomm`:

```
# lastcomm xyz.sh
xyz.sh               X ale      pts/1      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 14:12
xyz.sh               X root     pts/3      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 14:00
xyz.sh               X ale      pts/4      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 14:08
xyz.sh               X ale      pts/4      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 14:00
xyz.sh               X root     pts/4      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 13:54
xyz.sh               X ale      pts/1      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 13:51
xyz.sh               X root     pts/3      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 13:42
xyz.sh               X ale      pts/1      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 13:36
xyz.sh               X ale      pts/1      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 13:36
xyz.sh               X ale      pts/1      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 13:36
xyz.sh               X ale      pts/1      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 13:36
xyz.sh               X postgres pts/1      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 13:36
xyz.sh               X ale      pts/1      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 13:36
xyz.sh               X root     pts/1      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 13:36
xyz.sh               X ale      pts/1      0.00 secs Fri Sep 11 13:36
```

It's possible install the command `lastcomm` from the `psacct` (centos/redhat) or `acct` package (debian/ubuntu/OpenSuse).

Comment: Ok. @Arunjith, I ask you to accept my answer, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).